# Data truncated for column 'temp' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, amazon-ec2

i have deployed a simple Django application on AWS. The database i use is MySQL. Most parts of this application runs well. But there happens to be a problem when i submitted a form and store data from the form into a model. The error page presents `Data truncated for column 'temp' at row 1`. `temp` is a `ChoiceField` like this: `temp = forms.ChoiceField(label="temperature", choices=TEMP)`, in the model file the `temp` is a `CharField` like this `temp = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TEMP)`. The error happens at `.save()`. How can i fix this problem? Any advice and help is appreciated. BTW, as what i have searched, the truncation problem happens because of data type to be stored in database. But i still cannot figure out how to modify my code.

Comment: What are your choices, e.g. what is the value of `TEMP`?

Comment: Hi, my value of `TEMP` is TEMP = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

Comment: BTW, it runs well on my local server which is SQLite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is only 2 chars wide, but you are trying to store the strings 'HIGH', 'MEDIUM', 'LOW' from your `TEMP` choices (the first value of each tuple is saved in the database). Increase `max_length` or choose different values for choices, e.g. `TEMP = ( ('H', 'High'), ('M', 'Medium'), ('L', 'Low'), )`.

It worked fine in SQLite because SQLite simply ignores the `max_length` attribute (and other things).

Answer (score 2):

The error you are having is because `HIGH`, `MEDIUM`, `LOW` are greater than 2 characters. Redefined your choices so that value of a choice should not exceed the characters limit `max_length=2`as set by your field `temp`:

```
TEMP = (
    ('H', 'High'),
    ('M', 'Medium'),
    ('L', 'Low'),
)
```